# Calculate age average from age in month day format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have ages in month.day format like this:

```
35,24
36,11
36,19
37,18
35,12
37,04
35,20
36,01
35,26
36,05
36,16
37,28
```

for example for the first entry, the age is 35 months and 24 days.
How can I average them all to get a proper age average in the same format?

Thanks

Comment: How many days in a month?

Comment: I think any average is going to approximate because how can you convert months to days if you don't which exact months are in the numbers. One possible way to do is the break out the months in one column `=Left(A1,2)` and days in another `=Right(A1,2)`, then average them both and bring them back to together. Again, its approximate, but it may be the *easiest* solution.

Comment: I guess you might be able to work it out if you knew a specific date these values where calculated based on, but it's not gonna be pretty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it can be reasonably assumed that a **month** is equal to 30 days then the following will return an average in the form of *mm,dd*.

```
=INT((SUMPRODUCT(LEFT(A2:A13, FIND(",", A2:A13)-1)*30+MID(A2:A13, FIND(",", A2:A13)+1, 99))/ROWS(A2:A13))/30)&
  ","&
  INT(MOD((SUMPRODUCT(LEFT(A2:A13, FIND(",", A2:A13)-1)*30+MID(A2:A13, FIND(",", A2:A13)+1, 99))/ROWS(A2:A13)),30))
```

[image: average_dumb_dates]

Comment: I rounded off to the day as did you. I'm sure that there are some hours and minutes that make up the difference. If the months were a wider scope (they only range from 35 to 37) the multiplicand would also make a larger difference.

Comment: how can I get the standard deviation for the same data set? how can we adapt the formula to get the standard deviation in the same format as we got the average? I have created a new question here is the link, feel free to answer it in the new question http://stackoverflow.com/q/35784603/4835480

Answer (score 2):

Here is a rough approximation:

[image]

My formula in B14:

```
=ROUNDDOWN((SUM(B2:B13)*30.5+SUM(C2:C13))/(ROW(B14)-2)/30.5, 0)
```

- Sum of the months times 30.5 (rough avg days in month)
- Add the sum of the days
- Divide by the entries (made this flexible for flexible amount of entries)
- Divide out by days to get months average and rounddown

My formula in C14:

```
=ROUNDDOWN((SUM(B2:B13)*30.5+SUM(C2:C13))/(ROW(B14)-2)-(B14*30.5), 0)
```

- Sum of months and days again to get total days
- Divide by entries to get average days
- Subtract out days already accounted for in months (B14)
- Rounddown

Answer (score 2):

Upon doing the question on STDDEV I found I just need to change to average to get the answer for this:

```
=QUOTIENT(AVERAGE(LEFT(A1:A12,2)*30 + RIGHT(A1:A12,2)),30)&","&ROUND(MOD(AVERAGE(LEFT(A1:A12,2)*30 + RIGHT(A1:A12,2)),30),2)
```

It is an array formula so it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter. You can change the rounding on the days to what every you want by changing the last number in the formula.

[image]