# Standard deviation for age data in month day format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following data set, which represents ages in months and days.
For example, the first entry is 35 months and 24 days. How can I calculate the standard deviation for this list in the same format, month,day?

```
35,24
36,11
36,19
37,18
35,12
37,04
35,20
36,01
35,26
36,05
36,16
37,28
```

thanks

Comment: What is the answer you are expecting? A quick parse turns up ~23½ days which isn't even a month by any standard. btw, there are no less than seven variations on the [STDEV function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/STDEV-function-51FECAAA-231E-4BBB-9230-33650A72C9B0) ([STDEV.P](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/STDEV-P-function-6E917C05-31A0-496F-ADE7-4F4E7462F285), [STDEV.S](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/STDEV-S-function-7D69CF97-0C1F-4ACF-BE27-F3E83904CC23), etc). Perhaps you could clarify which you are leaning towards.

Comment: @ScottCraner - 30/month. Same as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748782).

Comment: The expected answer will look like for example: 1 month and 2 days, or sometimes, even not a month, for example, 0 month and 25 days.
I am looking for standard deviation for sample.

Comment: I know what it is supposed to look like; I asked what is the answer given the sample data above.

Comment: @Jeeped unfortunately i don't know the standard dev for the sample above. I am myself trying to find it. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
=QUOTIENT(STDEV.S(LEFT(A1:A12,2)*30 + RIGHT(A1:A12,2)),30)&","&ROUND(MOD(STDEV.S(LEFT(A1:A12,2)*30 + RIGHT(A1:A12,2)),30),2)
```

It is an array formula so it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  You can change the rounding on the days to what every you want by changing the last number in the formula.

[image]

Comment: I added a similar question but this time on statistical difference of ages. Could you also please help on this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35795121/statistical-difference-between-four-groups-with-age-data-in-month-day-format